# Select first and last element with particular class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of spans with particular class "place" and some of them have class "activated". Is there a way to select the first item with class "activated" and the last?

```
<span class="place" onclick="activate();">1</span>
<span class="place" onclick="activate();">2</span>
<span class="place activated" onclick="activate()">3</span>
<span class="place activated" onclick="activate();">4</span>
<span class="place activated" onclick="activate();">5</span>
<span class="place activated" onclick="activate();">6</span>
<span class="place" onclick="activate();">7</span>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var firstspan = $('span.activated:first'),
    lastspan = $('span.activated:last');
```

By the way, if you're using jQuery, what's with all the inline click events?

You could add some code like so:

```
$('span.place').click(function() {
    activate(); // you can add `this` as a parameter
                // to activate if you need scope.
});
```

Comment: I have a lot of those spans and in each one of them theres this activate function with different atributes, so I think its better that way. Thanks for great reply

Answer (score 14):

```
var places = $('span.place.activated');

var first = places.first(),
    last  = places.last();
```

Explanation: The `span.places.activated` selector will get all `<span>`s with both "place" and "activated" classes. Then the `first()` and `last()` methods will return the first and last items of that set. This is preferable to using the `:first` and `:last` pseudoselectors because selection is expensive and this way we only do selection once and then rely on (cheap) array operations to get the first and last elements.

Comment: +1 'cause I agree with patrick.  This is probably the better answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you take care about performance, than better use `$('span.place.activated')` instead  `$('.activated:first')`. 
But, in this case, the second variant correct too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = $('.activated:first');
var last = $('.activated:last');
```